# Does Go development require a paid Github account for private development?

Tags: git, svn, github, go

I'm just getting started with Go. I use subversion for most of my development, but the Go tutorial seems to assume that everything is hosted on Github in either a public repository or a (paid) private repository. It looks like I'm forced to choose between:

1. committing to everybody having access to everything I write,
2. spending $7 a month for a private Github repository,
3. not using source code control or
4. losing the ability to use Go's get/import facility properly

Am I missing something here, or is this really the case?

Comment: Bitbucket has free private repos.

Comment: This is offtopic on StackOverflow, IMO.

Comment: It's a question about how to do development in Go. I'd have thought that that's pretty directly relevant to SO.

Comment: Go has nothing to do with GutHub, it's just community who chose to share most of the open-source packages there. And `go get` is only a _convenient_ tool which supports GitHub repositories (but also other). You can use any source control system and keep it anywhere – just in some cases `go get` will not work and you will need to checkout repositories manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`go get` supports most git, mercurial, bazaar & svn repos, so your own Git server, Bitbucket, GitLab, etc are all acceptable. This is touched on in the docs here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackagePaths

Similarly, you can just create a `$GOPATH/src/yourname/yourpkg` dir, but you will have a harder time sharing your code with others.

In addition, you can use [remote import paths](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) (aka "vanity domains") to allow `go get scott.com/pkg/usefulthing` instead of directly pointing to GitHub, etc. Useful as you can avoid being tied to a single platform, should you wish to move in the future.

Answer (score 3):

"go get" and the "import" statement both support [several remote repositories](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths), including:

- Bitbucket (Git, Mercurial)
- GitHub (Git)
- Launchpad (Bazaar)
- IBM DevOps Services (Git)

as well as syntax for code hosted on other servers:

> For code hosted on other servers, import paths may either be qualified
>   with the version control type, or the go tool can dynamically fetch
>   the import path over https/http and discover where the code resides
>   from a <meta> tag in the HTML.
>
> To declare the code location, an import path of the form
>
> repository.vcs/path specifies the given repository, with or without
>   the .vcs suffix, using the named version control system, and then the
>   path inside that repository. The supported version control systems
>   are:
>
> - Bazaar      .bzr
> - Git         .git
> - Mercurial   .hg
> - Subversion  .svn

Comment: How did my answer get downvoted at the very instant that I submitted it?

Comment: It's not directly related, but the many import paths pointing to GitHub often causes newcomers to think that GitHub is the only choice.

Comment: Just note we're talking precisely about `go get` here and not general go development. `go get` is a handy tool for fetching packages from the internet, but `go build` doesn't care about github and such – when seeing `import "github.com/some/pkg"` it just treats it as a _path_ in file system to lookup (relatively to `$GOPATH/src` or `vendor` directory in your project).

Comment: The thing that tripped me up was the suggestion in https://golang.org/doc/code.html (How to write Go code) that a Github repo is *the* way to start a project. The comments here have been very helpful in understanding the topic better.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to *be* on Github yourself to use other available repos on Github. Bitbucket offers unlimited private repositories. You can even choose to have a completely local git repository (not using any git hosting service), and still use repos available on Github.